# Spring Security Taglibs control statement

Tags: spring-security

Is there a way to implement control statement with Spring Security taglibs?

Currently we can only check if a user has a role...

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   // display something
</security:authorize>
```

How about else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value of the `access` attribute is a [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) expression, evaluated against [`WebSecurityExpressionRoot`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/WebSecurityExpressionRoot.html), so you can use all its methods and all SpEL syntax.

Also you can customize creation of the evaluation context by declaring a custom [`WebSecurityExpressionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/WebSecurityExpressionHandler.html) as a bean (then you can add your own methods and variables).

Comment: I use the following to simulate a control statement

<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        got com admin
</security:authorize>
<security:authorize access="!hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        no com admin
</security:authorize>

Comment: Is it just me or does this not answer the question? I want to write `<c:choose><c:when test="hasRole('SUPERUSER')">superuser</c:when><c:otherwise>ordinary user</c:otherwise></c:choose>`. It doesn't work. Why doesn't it work, and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 19):

The question is old, but anyway..

You can store the result of tag evaluation into variable (at least at version 3.1) and then use it within standard `if/else` construction. I think this is more useful solution than previous one.

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" var="isAdmin" />
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${isAdmin}">superuser</c:when>
   <c:otherwise>ordinary user</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Hello, which "3.1" spec version are you referring to? "Servlet 3.1 / JSP spec 2.3", or "Servlet 6.0 / JSP spec 3.1"?  https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I am sorry I don't remember anymore. But I think I meant the version of the spring-security taglibs, not the servlet or jsp.

Answer (score 6):

If you missed the comment of the accepted answer. Here is how to make a control statement out of `<security:authorize>`

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    // IF -- display something
</security:authorize>

<security:authorize access="!hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    // ELSE -- display something
</security:authorize>
```

Notice the `!` not statement in else condition

credits to `@Blake`